# How do I remove these escutcheons from my door?

Tags: doors, lock

I have a G-U multi-point door lock. The inside escutcheon with handle and thumb turn are pictured below. I am trying to figure out what type of lock cylinder I have inside of the door, but I can't see how I can easily remove the escutcheon / back plate on either side of the door.

Removing the handle from each side is easy. I do not see how to remove either the key turn (other side, outside) or the thumb turn (inside). The escutcheon has a small hole at the top (see below) where a flathead screwdriver will fit for prying, but the piece feels strongly attached to the door and I am afraid I will break it.

What am I missing?

[image: door mechanism]

Comment: With the handle and knob off prying at the notch in the plate looks to be the right thing, is there a notch at the bottom? One side might be easier than the other.

Comment: He stated that he doesn't know how to remove the thumb knob.  That's probably the _key_ to removing the plate.

Comment: Based on the pictures [here](https://www.allaboutdoors.com/Article-How-to-Replace-a-GU-Ferco-Multipoint-Lock-in-a-Pella-Door), the thumb latch might stay attached to the plate.  Remove the door lever, then the plate, but this could be a different design.

Comment: Right. I’m not sure if the thumb turn is part of the plate or not, but I don’t see any obvious method of removing it. So far, prying the plate feels a little too brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All GU hardware I have installed, the plate is a pressure fit in place, the notches you see are for removal. The thumbturn in many cases, but maybe not this one, has been in the past, a one piece unit with the cylinder. The torx head screw on the edge is about 3" long and is threaded into the cylinder, usually.

The picture with its angle does not show the bottom half of what may be the cylinder that the thumbturn is a part of. A picture of the outside of the door may reveal the key slot, so I would assume.  Never the less, if it is put together like all the others I have worked on, removing the torx (star)screw will allow the cylinder to be removed from the thumbturn side and after the handles are removed the escutcheon can be gently pried off by working the top a little, then the bottom, and so on until it comes free.

If you have a putty knife to hold at the top edge while the screwdriver is rotating to start prying the cover plate off, it will prevent any damage to the nice finish you have on the door. o the same with the bottom slot too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the thumb turn does not have any exposed screws.

Comment: The torx screw I was referring to is on the edge of the door

Comment: There are 3 Torx screws on the edge of the door. Would I need to remove all 3?

Comment: Adding that the Torx screws are pretty shallow (5cm?) and don't appear to reach past the faceplate.

Comment: Maybe the camera angle is throwing me off a bit. There should be one screw on the edge that lines up with the thumbturn. If not then it is made different than the ones I  worked on.

Comment: Turns your your putty knife suggestion worked. I just had to trust that brute force was the way to go. It snaps on/off.

Comment: Did the thumbturm come off with it? Or did you find the screw that removed the cylinder/thumbturn?

Comment: The thumbturn did come off with it.